# fetch OPTIONS return HTTP 401 while Curl Command succeeds

Tags: javascript, rest, curl, fetch-api

This is what my fetch code looks like

```
let getSummary = (year, month) => {
        let url = baseUrl + "/rest/monthlySummaries/" +
            localStorage.getItem("paUserId") + "/" + year + "/" + month;

        let authHeaders = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Bearer": localStorage.getItem("paToken")
        };

        console.log("summary url:", url, ",headers:", authHeaders);
        return fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            headers: authHeaders
        });
    };
```

Since this is `GET` request, browsers make `preflight` reqeusts using `HTTP OPTIONS` to make sure that they make indeed make `HTTP GET` requests. I log what call is made, I see

```
summary url: https://api.myapp.com/rest/monthlySummaries/userId/2017/4 ,headers: Object {Content-Type: "application/json", Accept: "application/json", Bearer: "41afa8432aaa411e48b6c1c637c77cb3:userId:84000000"}Accept: "application/json"Bearer: "41afa8432aaa411e48b6c1c637c77cb3:userId:84000000"Content-Type: "application/json"__proto__: Object
2VM50885:1 OPTIONS https://api.myapp.com/rest/monthlySummaries/cca6b151-cab4-4de2-81db-9a739a62ae88/2017/4 401 (Unauthorized)
```

While, when I do similar thing on `curl`, everything works

```
curl -v -X OPTIONS -H"BEARER:e3310afc4dcd68d80d56a83bddfd4a09:userId:564000000" "https://api.myapp.com/rest/monthlySummaries/userId/2017/4"
*   Trying 52.23.254.96...
* Connected to api.myapp.com (52.23.254.96) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
* Server certificate: DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
> OPTIONS /rest/monthlySummaries/userId/2017/4 HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.myapp.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> BEARER:e3310afc4dcd68d80d56a83bddfd4a09:userId:564000000
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 23:21:11 GMT
< Server: WildFly/8
< X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization
< Allow: HEAD, GET, OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 18
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
< Access-Control-Max-Age: 1209600
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
* Connection #0 to host api.myapp.com left intact
```

Why the behavior is so different? What am I missing in `fetch`?

**UPDATE**
My `server` enables `CORS` support

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext,
      ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
    containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
    containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    containerResponseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
  }
}
```

This can be seen in the response as well

Comment: it's CORS request, so You need to serve `OPTIONS` method, is it nodejs app on serverside? if YES so just install CORS package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and do `app.use(require('cors')());`

Comment: Yes, the server is little itchy, but as you can see the response on `CURL` response with right headers and authenticates as well

Comment: @daydreamer simple curl will not do preflight request to get cors allowed methods, but browser fetch code will do. So again: needed to server OPTIONS method from server with 200 OK status.

Answer (score 1):

See where you have configured

```
.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
```

You haven't allowed the `Bearer` header, nor is it the correct way to pass a [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519).

You probably meant

```
"Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("paToken")}`
```

Sending `Bearer` when it isn't in the allowed headers list will fail the pre-flight validation.

Comment: totally agree (: